# can a buttongroup have a label?

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm developing a Gutenberg block, and am trying to create some InspectorControls. I would like to create a buttongroup to control the alignment of a specific element within the block (I would add that I'm using ServerSideRender to render the block). There isn't much information in the handbook about ButtonGroup, it doesn't seem to take a "label".
My javascript code right now is:

```js
    createElement(PanelRow, {},
        createElement(ButtonGroup, { title: __('N Element Alignment','bibleget-io') },
            createElement(IconButton, {
                icon: 'editor-alignleft',
                isDefault: true
            }),
            createElement(IconButton, {
                icon: 'editor-aligncenter',
                isDefault: true
            }),
            createElement(IconButton, {
                icon: 'editor-alignright',
                isDefault: true
            })
        )
    ),
```

I would also like to know if the **ButtonGroup** has an **onChange** event, or only the single **Button**s in the group? Or perhaps an **onClick** event? How would I set the value of the **ButtonGroup**? Would I have to set the state of each button based on an attribute's value?

**UPDATE:**
I saw the "deprecated" notices in the chrome inspector tools as regards "IconButton" (so I'm just using "Button" now) and as regards the "isDefault" property so I'm using "isSecondary" now.
I found that I can actually set a **value** property on each button.
And so far the only way I can find to set the state of each button in a significant manner based on the value of a single attribute is in this manner:

```js
createElement(PanelRow, {},
    createElement(ButtonGroup, { title: __('N Element Alignment','bibleget-io') },
        createElement(Button, {
            icon: 'editor-alignleft',
            value: 'left',
            isPrimary: (attributes.nalignment === 'left'),
            isSecondary: (attributes.nalignment !== 'left'),
            onClick: changeNAlignmentValue
        }),
        createElement(Button, {
            icon: 'editor-aligncenter',
            value: 'center',
            isPrimary: (attributes.nalignment === 'center'),
            isSecondary: (attributes.nalignment !== 'center'),
            onClick: changeNAlignmentValue
        }),
        createElement(Button, {
            icon: 'editor-alignright',
            value: 'right',
            isPrimary: (attributes.nalignment === 'right'),
            isSecondary: (attributes.nalignment !== 'right'),
            onClick: changeNAlignmentValue
        })
    )
),
```

The button states are now showing in a more significant manner based on the value of my **nalignment** attribute. 
When I click on a button in the group I see that the click event is being passed to the **changeNAlignmentValue** function. I am able to read the value of the button that was clicked like this:

```js
function changNAlignmentValue(ev){
    let nalignment = ev.currentTarget.value;
    setAttributes({nalignment});
}
```

In this manner I see that my **nalignment** attribute is updating correctly and state is being set on the buttons in the **ButtonGroup** based on the value of the **nalignment** attribute. Is this the correct approach to using the ButtonGroup? I would have expected it to have more of a radio functionality, seeing that the documentation says that only one button can be toggled at a time (when used in the exclusive radio like manner: how would you set a ButtonGroup as exclusive rather than multiple, which would act more like a checkbox buttongroup?)
And I still have the question of how to put a label on the **ButtonGroup**. If it's not possible, I would even just create a **Text** component immediately before creating the **ButtonGroup** component, but I can't find any documentation on how to create a **Text** componenent in javascript. I have tried a couple things but I get errors like "was expecting string and found expression"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered a way of creating a **label** and a **help** property for a component that doesn't have it's own **label** or **help** properties, by wrapping that component in a **BaseControl** component. Here is my working solution:

```js
createElement(PanelRow, {}, 
    createElement(BaseControl, { 
            label: __('N element alignment', 'my-textdomain'), 
            help: __('Set the alignment for n element in this block','my-textdomain') 
        },
        createElement(ButtonGroup, {},
            createElement(Button, {
                icon: 'editor-alignleft',
                value: 'left',
                isPrimary: (attributes.nelementalign === 'left'),
                isSecondary: (attributes.nelementalign !== 'left'),
                onClick: changeNElementAlign,
                title: __('N element align left', 'my-textdomain')
            }),
            createElement(Button, {
                icon: 'editor-aligncenter',
                value: 'center',
                isPrimary: (attributes.nelementalign === 'center'),
                isSecondary: (attributes.nelementalign !== 'center'),
                onClick: changeNElementAlign,
                title: __('N element align center', 'my-textdomain')
            }),
            createElement(Button, {
                icon: 'editor-alignright',
                value: 'right',
                isPrimary: (attributes.nelementalign === 'right'),
                isSecondary: (attributes.nelementalign !== 'right'),
                onClick: changeNElementAlign,
                title: __('N element align right', 'my-textdomain')
            })
        )                               
    )
),
```